# Why are we associating hostname while creating mysql pool in Node Js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a newbie to Node JS and MySql Pool.

My Requirements

1. I've to build a server accepting HTTP request with MYSQL query as payload
   and returning the query output in form of json.
2. Databases that I'll access can be in multiple machines.
3. So basically connection pool should hold connections for different hostname.

After learning from various Node js tutorials, I'm finding that they are fixing the hostname during the pool creation itself.

I've seen two ways to manage a pool of mysql connections in Node JS

**Method #1 Using [mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)**

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});
```

**Method #2 Using [mysql-pool](https://github.com/Kijewski/node-mysql-pool)**

```
var MySQLPool = require("mysql-pool").MySQLPool;
var pool = new MySQLPool({
  poolSize: 4,
  user:     'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'test'
});
```

Is there anything illogical the way I presumed ? How can I simply get a connection object from the pool, set hostname and other stuffs dynamically before using the connection ?

Comment: The `mysql-pool` project site starts with **(!! The project is dead !!) **. You think is is a good sign? (Last commit 3 years ago.)